# 3D CNN parameter calculation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a CNN code that was written using tensorflow library:

```
x_img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)    
def convnet_3d(x_img, W):
        conv_3d_layer = tf.nn.conv3d(x_img, W, strides=[1,1,1,1,1], padding='VALID')

        return conv_3d_layer

    def maxpool_3d(x_img):
        maxpool_3d_layer = tf.nn.max_pool3d(x_img, ksize=[1,2,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,2,1], padding='VALID')

        return maxpool_3d_layer

    def convolutional_neural_network(x_img):
            weights = {'W_conv1_layer':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,1,32])),
                       'W_conv2_layer':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,32,64])),
                       'W_fc_layer':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([409600,1024])),
                       'W_out_layer':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, num_classes]))}

            biases = {'b_conv1_layer':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
                       'b_conv2_layer':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
                       'b_fc_layer':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
                       'b_out_layer':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))}

            x_img = tf.reshape(x_img, shape=[-1, img_x, img_y, img_z, 1])

            conv1_layer = tf.nn.relu(convnet_3d(x_img, weights['W_conv1_layer']) + biases['b_conv1_layer'])
            conv1_layer = maxpool_3d(conv1_layer)


            conv2_layer = tf.nn.relu(convnet_3d(conv1_layer, weights['W_conv2_layer']) + biases['b_conv2_layer'])
            conv2_layer = maxpool_3d(conv2_layer)

            fc_layer = tf.reshape(conv2_layer,[-1, 409600])
            fc_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc_layer, weights['W_fc_layer'])+biases['b_fc_layer'])
            fc_layer = tf.nn.dropout(fc_layer, keep_rate)

            output_layer = tf.matmul(fc_layer, weights['W_out_layer'])+biases['b_out_layer']

            return output_layer
```

my input image x_img is 25x25x25(3d image), I have some questions about the code:

1- is [3,3,3,1,32] in 'W_conv1_layer' means [width x height x depth x channel x number of filters]?

2- in 'W_conv2_layer' weights are [3,3,3,32,64], why the output is 64? I know that 3x3x3 is filter size and 32 is input come from first layer.

3- in 'W_fc_layer' weights are [409600,1024], 1024 is number of nodes in FC layer, but where this magic number '409600' come from?

4- before the image get into the conv layers why we need to reshape the image

```
x_img = tf.reshape(x_img, shape=[-1, img_x, img_y, img_z, 1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers can be found in the [official doc of conv3d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d).

1. The weights should be [filter_depth, filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
2. The numbers 32 and 64 are chosen because it works simply they are just hyperparameters
3. 409600 comes from reshaping the output of maxpool3d (it is probably a mistake the real size should be 4096 see comments)
4. Because tensorflow expects certain layouts for its input

Your should try implementing a simple convnet on images before moving to more complicated stuff.

Comment: I will add that I would not have written the code that way especially for the placeholders I am surprised it works at all.

Comment: Adding some information on the shape of the placeholders beforehand is good practice.

Comment: thank you for your answer, tell me how you write the code for your placeholders and I know that 409600 comes from maxpool3d layer but how can I calculate it? for example, if the image changed to 32X32X32

Comment: Your padding is valid so on each spatial dimensions you substract the filter dimensions and you add 1 that is for convolutions for max-pooling you do an integer division of each spatial dimensions by 2. Your questions have already been answered a bazillion times for 2D CNNs for 3D CNNs it is the same.

Comment: I have to add that you can run each tensor to see their shape if you are unsure.

Comment: For instance if you start with a 25x25x25x1 3D volume you get 23x23x23x32 then 11x11x11x32 then 9x9x9x64 then 4x4x4x64=4096, no idea where the *100 comes probably a mistake.

Comment: I do same calculation as you do, you are right probably there is a mistake but I do not know where is the problem.

Comment: thank you very much, after changing the number to 4096 or 4x4x4x64, the model works fine.